# When ever i change my DNS server to a public one i lose connectivity?

Tags: dns, connection

I went and changed my WiFi adapters DNS settings to use a public server instead of ISP ones. however when i do so i cant resolve any DNS requests.

looked online cant find any helpful piece of information regarding this issue.

Comment: Did you check if you can reach the DNS server by ping or traceroute?

Also did you try with multiple DNS servers?

Comment: Idid try cloud flare, google, quad9 dns servers, yes i can ping them all but cant use them which doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps your ISP blocks all DNS queries unless you use their own. Perhaps your firewall has not been opened sufficiently. I suggest you try traceroute using the DNS port.

Comment: to be honest have no idea how to do that, can provide an example, i only know normal tracert